# powershell rename all files in a folder to a pattern

Tags: powershell

I am very new to powershell. I have a folder with multiple files, each file name is like:

File1_backup_2016_09_01_095444_1628350.bak

Need to rename all of them to Filex_yyyymmdd.bak

Comment: Such basic tasks are usually easy to solve by [googling an existing solution](https://www.google.com/#q=stackoverflow+powershell+rename+files+by+date). N.B. StackOverflow isn't google.

Comment: Or if you know regexp you can [instantly find examples](https://www.google.com/#q=powershell%20rename%20files%20using%20regexp) of using that in PS to rename files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar should works for you:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" |foreach {
    $SplitName = $_.Name -split '_'
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "$($SplitName[0])_$($SplitName[2])$($SplitName[3])$($SplitNa‌​me[4]).bak"
}
```

Comment: It says: Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'AIB_backup_2016_09_01_095444_1628350.bak' does not exist. (I have changed path to correct one and get-childitem works, also tested split parameter and can see the different data parts)

Comment: I changed the example and it should work now. Need to use $_.FullName  insetad $_ in rename comand

Comment: That runs but I need something like this, File1_20160901.bak, File1 is the part before the first _ in original file name.

Comment: then: 
 `Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "$($SplitName[0])_$($SplitName[2])$($SplitName[3])$($SplitName[4]).bak"`. 
Do you understand what this commands are doing?

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. Can you please update your answer?